# Extract fields out of a ruby hash with special chars

Tags: ruby, hash, pdf-generation

I'm working to turn a pdf signature visible, using origami.pdf, and meanwhile I noticed that my signature is an hash, and so I try to capture fields like "Location", "Reason", "Date", "ContactInfo".

```
{/Type=>/Sig, /Contents=>"0\x82\a\xAE\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x01\a\x02\xA0\x82\a\
x9F0\x82\a\x9B\x02\x01\x011\v0\t\x06\x05+\x0E\x03\x02\x1A\x05\x000#\x06\t*\x86H\
x86\xF7\r\x01\a\x01\xA0\x16\x04\x14\xEF8uEn1@\x11M\x95\xE4\xD7\x9C\xFE(\xCF\xB7\
x92\x01\xC2\xA0\x82\x05\x970\x82\x05\x930\x82\x04{\xA0\x03\x02\x01\x02\x02\x04Bo
\x93\x8C0\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x01\x01\x05\x05\x000>1\v0\t\x06\x03U\x04\x06\x
13\x02pt1\x150\x13\x06\x03U\x04\n\x13\fMULTICERT-CA1\x180\x16\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x
13\x0FMULTICERT-CA 020\x1E\x17\r130320170147Z\x17\r140320164736Z0\x81\xA51\v0\t\
x06\x03U\x04\x06\x13\x02PT1\x150\x13\x06\x03U\x04\n\x13\fMULTICERT-CA1\x160\x14\
x06\x03U\x04\v\x13\rCERTIPOR - RA1\x120\x10\x06\x03U\x04\v\x13\tCorporate1 0\x1E
\x06\x03U\x04\v\x13\x17ESCRITA INTELIGENTE LDA1\x180\x16\x06\x03U\x04\v\x13\x0FW
eb Application1\x170\x15\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x13\x0ERECIBOS ONLINE0\x81\x9F0\r\x06\
t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x01\x01\x01\x05\x00\x03\x81\x8D\x000\x81\x89\x02\x81\x81\x00\x
AC\xCE\xA4\x06\x901\xB5x\x89lE\rw\xC8<\x13\xDDu\xC6h\xBF'b6\x8D\xB0\xA0\xB1Y\e\x
18\x00\xE5\x8C\x1A\xCD\xBB%\xDA\x15P\x1A\xF91\xF9\xF6\xBA\xE0\xF8\xF6LH\x16\x86\
xE9Y\xDE\x00Z\xEC\x82\xB3=\r2fP7\xD1\x8B\xF3k\xF7|MVb\fB\xFB\xBA\x92\xD3\xFF9\x7
F\x9D\x83w\xFE\xAB\xBA\x93G\x8F\xCE\xF0\t!d\x83\xD3F\xAC\xCCv\xCA\x10\xC9\xB8e;\
x80\xB8\xF6\xEBI\xBD\x93\x89zC\xDF\x06-\r\x9E\xD3\x02\x03\x01\x00\x01\xA3\x82\x0
2\xB30\x82\x02\xAF0\v\x06\x03U\x1D\x0F\x04\x04\x03\x02\x03\xF808\x06\b+\x06\x01\
x05\x05\a\x01\x01\x04,0*0(\x06\b+\x06\x01\x05\x05\a0\x01\x86\x1Chttp://ocsp.mult
icert.com/ca0\x81\xE0\x06\x03U\x1D \x04\x81\xD80\x81\xD50M\x06\t+\x06\x01\x04\x0
1\xB0<\n\x020@0>\x06\b+\x06\x01\x05\x05\a\x02\x01\x162http://www.multicert.com/c
ps/multicert-ca-cps.html0\x81\x83\x06\v+\x06\x01\x04\x01\xB0<\n\x02\x88\x060t0r\
x06\b+\x06\x01\x05\x05\a\x02\x020f\x1Ed\x00h\x00t\x00t\x00p\x00:\x00/\x00/\x00w\
x00w\x00w\x00.\x00m\x00u\x00l\x00t\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00r\x00t\x00.\x00c\x00o\x00m\
x00/\x00c\x00p\x00/\x00m\x00u\x00l\x00t\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00r\x00t\x00-\x00c\x00a\
x00-\x001\x000\x003\x000\x00.\x00h\x00t\x00m\x00l0\x11\x06\t`\x86H\x01\x86\xF8B\
x01\x01\x04\x04\x03\x02\x04\xB00 \x06\x03U\x1D\x11\x04\x190\x17\x81\x15info@reci
bosonline.pt0\x82\x01\x01\x06\x03U\x1D\x1F\x04\x81\xF90\x81\xF60\x81\x9A\xA0\x81
\x97\xA0\x81\x94\x86/http://www.multicert.com/ca/multicert-ca-02.crl\x86aldap://
ldap.multicert.com/cn=MULTICERT-CA%2002,o=MULTICERT-CA,c=PT?certificateRevocatio
nList?base0W\xA0U\xA0S\xA4Q0O1\v0\t\x06\x03U\x04\x06\x13\x02pt1\x150\x13\x06\x03
U\x04\n\x13\fMULTICERT-CA1\x180\x16\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x13\x0FMULTICERT-CA 021\x0F
0\r\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x13\x06CRL2950\x1F\x06\x03U\x1D#\x04\x180\x16\x80\x14\x1D\x
C3\xB9\x88\xA5\x18\xBE`\xA7,\xA6c\xCAf*\xFC\f'\xC1\xBD0\x1D\x06\x03U\x1D\x0E\x04
\x16\x04\x14\x06\xD8\x1Fr6a\x9E\xEB\x176\x9C)\x9E-t\xFF\xD080\x190\t\x06\x03U\x1
D\x13\x04\x020\x000\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x01\x01\x05\x05\x00\x03\x82\x01\x01\
x00AQ\x1F\xCD\\ua\x98\e\rT2kW\xF7\xB8|CZ\xAC\xB7\xA2\x96(\bv\x83\x13\x89*\xB1@r7
\xE9WW{\x87T\x14\xDE\x81\nA2?\x9E\nv\x8E\x9A\xC4\\\x0Ff\xAE\t<2\xC1\x14S\xC6F?\x
85o\xEFb\xE2x!\x13M\xD0\x9Fu \x80\x00\x04\x0E\x89\xA8\x14\xE60\x96#\xC5\xD0Ac\xC
0<\xFD\xE31S\x90\x8A\xC3\xDF\xCA[\x1Cf\xC3\xDC\xB8\x96D\xA3\x03\x0F\xE7\x94\xD5\
v\xD2U\xD3\x96SZz\xF2g\xC3\xA58\x14{\x93q\xD0_#\xD8\xCAH\x1A\xEB\xC7\xD7\xA7\xD9
|.\x7F\xB5\xABI\xC4\xE4UNH\x00d\x8B\xC7k\x1A\xF5a*\x1D\x93a\xD1r\bNpi\t(\xA9\x11
\xFC \x983\xC5\x06!\x9C\xF1\x86\xB6P{Y\x9EL\x0FB\xF3\xBF#\xC2\xB8\xF0\xA0x\xD0\x
1D\x9B\xF5\xFDGF\xD9rS\xEEO\xE8\xF4rH\x9B=\xC2opr\xC6Xr\x18\x82[\xB3\x06\x10t\xB
9\xC2@\xF8\x92\x8D6\xFE\xFC\x0Fp\x88\x97u,\xD9F1\x82\x01\xC70\x82\x01\xC3\x02\x0
1\x010F0>1\v0\t\x06\x03U\x04\x06\x13\x02pt1\x150\x13\x06\x03U\x04\n\x13\fMULTICE
RT-CA1\x180\x16\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x13\x0FMULTICERT-CA 02\x02\x04Bo\x93\x8C0\t\x06
\x05+\x0E\x03\x02\x1A\x05\x00\xA0\x81\xD80\x18\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x01\t\x031\
v\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x01\a\x010\x1C\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x01\t\x051\x0F\x17\
r130329223127Z0#\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x01\t\x041\x16\x04\x14\x93\xD9l\xBD68\xDB
*M\xADY\xF8\x8F<\x8E\x94m\xACS\xAE0y\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x01\t\x0F1l0j0\v\x06\
t`\x86H\x01e\x03\x04\x01*0\v\x06\t`\x86H\x01e\x03\x04\x01\x160\v\x06\t`\x86H\x01
e\x03\x04\x01\x020\n\x06\b*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x03\a0\x0E\x06\b*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x03\
x02\x02\x02\x00\x800\r\x06\b*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x03\x02\x02\x01@0\a\x06\x05+\x0E\x0
3\x02\a0\r\x06\b*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x03\x02\x02\x01(0\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xF7\r\x01\x
01\x01\x05\x00\x04\x81\x803]\xBC\xA2\xC5\x0F&\r\x94\x96\xD5\xBD\xF2\x96\xB3\x86\
x9D\x01\xA3{5\xEC\xA5\xEC\x8B=\r\xD7%w0o\x9C\x7F\v\x17YX\x80\xAF\x1A\x8F\x1E\xBB
e\xBCp4\xF7\x80\x89b&?\xCE<\xCC\x8D\xFE\xEFK\x86\x0F\xD8Q\xFFU\x04\x11E\t\xED\xC
9=WF\x93\x10w\xC6g\xD4\e`\xE5\xB5{Ax~%\xE9\x92\xF5\x01\x19\xCDS\xE1|%\"\xB2\xC6\
x107\xE9\xF7M\xD7\xA3\x11MJ\xAF\x03\x0F\xFF\x8D:s\x84g\xB6\xD5o\xAF\xB0\x00\x00\
x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00", /Filter=>/Adobe.PPKMS, /SubFilter=>/adbe.pkcs7.sha1, /
ByteRange=>[0, 12883, 17081, 1098], /Location=>"Portugal", /ContactInfo=>"email@email.com", /Reason=>"Proof of Concept", /M=>"D:20130329223127Z00'00", /P
rop_Build=>{/Filter=>{/Name=>/Adobe.PPKMS, /R=>131101, /Date=>"2013-03-29 22:31:
27 +0000"}, /SigQ=>{/Preview=>false, /R=>131101}, /PubSec=>{/NonEFontNoWarn=>fal
se, /Date=>"2013-03-29 22:31:27 +0000", /R=>131101}, /App=>{/TrustedMode=>false,
 /OS=>[/Win], /R=>458752, /Name=>/Exchange-Pro}}}
```

If i extract the keys (`pdf.signature.keys`) i get

```
/Type
/Contents
/Filter
/SubFilter
/ByteRange
/Location
/ContactInfo
/Reason
/M
/Prop_Build
```

Now, how do I reach the contents of these keys ?

I cannot simply do `pdf.signature[/Location]` , because ruby says it is a syntax error...

Any ideas?

Comment: What about `pdf.signature['/Location']`?

Comment: then it isn't a match, because my key hasn't quotes around it :-S

Comment: I'm trying to find out if those are strings, because I have no idea which Ruby data type those keys belong to. What's the output of `pdf.signature.keys.first.class`?

Comment: interesting : Origami::Name

Comment: @MrWater: How about: `signature[Origami::Name.new('/Location')]`?

Comment: Doesn't work too @Linuxios, and i believe it is because the key is just /Location and not "/Location"

Comment: @MrWater: It't *can't*. There is no literal in Ruby of `/Location`. It has to be a string or some other datatype.

Comment: @MrWater: How did you get that representation of the hash?

Comment: puts pdf.signature.inspect

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27212/discussion-between-mrwater-and-linuxios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the source for origami-pdf, and it seems that the `/` prepending every key in that output is generated on-the-fly from `Origami::Name.to_s`. Also looking at its [`eql?`](https://code.google.com/p/origami-pdf/source/browse/lib/origami/name.rb#98) definition it seems like it just compares it to the underlying string value. So this should work, have you tried it?

```
signature[Origami::Name.new('Location')]
```

Comment: Thank you Jorge, great eyes. After your comment i went to check it and indeed, the to_s adds that token to the name `# File 'lib/origami/name.rb', line 106; def to_s  super(TOKENS.first + me.expand(@value)) end ` guess I will have to train my eyes better with ruby code analysis ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As generating an Origami::Name object with /Location seems to be so hard, I solved this with a different approach :

```
location = pdf.signature[pdf.signature.keys[5]]
```

The Output returns `Portugal`, and this is the approach I will take, since the array's keys position are supposed to be static.

I would appreciate a more elegant solution though